# Apply css settings to all clickable elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to apply `cursor: pointer;` to any element that has jQuery `click()` function bound to it.

How can I do this without going to each element in my CSS file and manually adding `cursor: pointer;` to it? (I have a lot of various clickable items)

```
<span class = "clickable1">something</span>
<span class = "clickable2">something</span>
<span class = "clickable3">something</span>

$(".clickable1").click(function(){
  //do something
});

$(".clickable2").click(function(){
  //do something
});

$(".clickable3").click(function(){
  //do something
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually can do this.
By checking the internal `$._data` you can get the bound events on any element, then it's just a matter of checking if `click` is one of those events and attaching the style etc.

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    var d = $._data( this, "events" );
    return d && 'click' in d;
}).css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6YTXp/)

Comment: Users of this solution should be warned that this isn't guaranteed to work on every jQuery version, since it is using a non-public API that can change without warning.

Comment: @RenatoZannon - that's true, `$._data` is not a public method, but something that is used internally by jQuery, so it's not guaranteed to work with future versions of jQuery, but by the way that it's used internally it probably won't be removed any time soon, but they could change it's name (they already did that a few versions ago), but as of right now, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Add another class called `isclickable` so you would have

```
<span class = "isclickable clickable1">something</span>
<span class = "isclickable clickable2">something</span>
<span class = "isclickable clickable3">something</span>
```

Then you can have `.isclickable { cursor: pointer; }` in your css

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: give every clickable element the same class like

```
<span class = "clickable clickable1">something</span>
<span class = "clickable clickable2">something</span>
<span class = "clickable clickable3">something</span>
```

Solution 2: expand jQuery selector `$(".clickable1, .clickable2, .clickable3")`

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a common class to all of them?

```
<span class = "clickable clickable1">something</span>
<span class = "clickable clickable2">something</span>
<span class = "clickable clickable3">something</span>
```

Then, with css:

```
.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

If you'd rather not change the HTML you already have manually (or if you can't), you can add the class when binding the event handlers:

```
function addClickBehavior($el, callback) {
  return $el.addClass("clickable").on("click", callback);
}

addClickBehavior($(".clickable1"), function(){
  //do something
});

addClickBehavior($(".clickable2"), function(){
  //do something
});

addClickBehavior($(".clickable3"), function(){
  //do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a selector that selects all elements whose class name starts with "clickable":

```
$("*[class^='clickable']").css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function(){
  //do something
});
```

BTW: Seems like a very "inefficient" use of the class attribute and class names aren't very "useful".